# C# Entity "entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

So I am trying to Delete some items from the database before I Insert some data. For some reason, C# Entity Framework and ASP.NET do not enjoy me doing this simple operation and gives out another one of those vague errors.

I am trying to update a set of rows of information in a table (using foreach loops and Insert/Delete), as well as some properties in another table (using update)

**How do I fix it? The error occurs on the Delete function, on the line:
this.entities.tableModule.Attach(module);**

*I get: "System.InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."*

```
public void Insert(tableModule module)
    {
        this.entities.tableModule.AddObject(module);
        this.entities.SaveChanges();
    }    
public void Delete(tableModule module)
    {
        this.entities.tableModule.Attach(module); // error HERE
        this.entities.DeleteObject(module);
        this.entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Further down the code I call Delete and Insert and Update for another table.

```
try
        {
            DifferentClass.Update(tu);
            foreach (tableModule mitem in list_to_del)
            {
                moduleclass.Delete(mitem); // remove all super roles by the user.
            }
            foreach (tableModule m_to_add in add_list)
            {
                moduleclass.Insert(m_to_add);
            }
        }
```

From what I gather, the attach function is maybe being run more than once and that for some reason is something that the designers of C# Entity Framework are completely caught by surprise for, and so they produce an error. Though it's most likely my complete lack of understanding of entity framework.

**EDIT:**
Here's how I get the list_to_del array.

```
List<tableModule> list_to_del = (from m in entities.tableModule where m.userid == (long)userID select m).ToList();
```

**EDIT2:**

New test code:

```
public void InsertQueue(tableModule module)
{
    this.entities.tableModule.AddObject(module);
}
public void DeleteQueue(tableModule module)
{
    this.entities.tableModule.Attach(module);
    this.entities.DeleteObject(module);
}
public void FinallySave(){
    this.entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

**EDIT 3 ---- SOLUTION -----**

The test code worked sort of (though inserts didn't for some odd reason). The problem was, I was calling list_to_del query to get that array of tableModules from a tableUser class which has its own entityset/context. So the results in list_to_del were of a different context, than the call to the class that does DeleteQueue / Insert etc.

I changed:

```
List<tableModule> list_to_del = (from m in entities.tableModule where m.userid == (long)userID select m).ToList();
```

to the appropriate class that has the SAME query:

```
List<tableModule> list_to_del = ModuleClass.GetListofModulesByUserID(userID);
```

Of course **ModuleClass.InsertQueue** and **ModuleClass.DeleteQueue** is called.

So everything uses the same entities object (context/entityset).

So the error happens when you call a query on a context, that returns a set of results that are ALREADY attached to that context. Then when you call Attach again, a problem occurs because they already are in a context on some other class/instance.

Comment: Your `list_to_del` could contain dupes or entities loaded from a context and not properly detached.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do some sort of check in Delete, like if(!AlreadyAttached)Attach  ??

Comment: List<tableModule> list_to_del = (from m in entities.tableModule where m.userid == (long)userID select m).ToList();    // Thats how I get list_to_del

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `Attach` if you loaded module from the same context instance - you can call `DeleteObject` directly. When you load entity from the context it is by default tracked by the context (= it is attached) and you cannot attach it again. You also cannot attach it to different context so make sure that `list_to_del` is loaded by the same context instance as you use for deletion (= it must be loaded in the same request processing because you should have a new context instance per request).

Comment: I don't know if I am going about this the right way, I really don't fully understand the need of attachments and contexts. But what if I made a function called InsertQueue and DeleteQueue which will simply call entities.AddObject() and DeleteObject(), and then FinallySave() which will call entities.SaveChanges()? Would that work better? I tried the following in the next comment, but now it says objects are not in object state manager.

Comment: Don't put the code in comments. It is unreadable. Modify your question if you need to pass another code. Also follow your initial naming. It is confusing if you start question with some example and you follow with different one. Read my answer again and think about the main points: usage of the context, source of `list_to_del`, relations between entities.

Comment: Yes there we go. I added it with correct naming onto EDIT2. I was trying it on different test page, so hence the problems with that code. Your answer is simply not clear. How do I know if it will be loaded in the same context or not. It's simply loaded in a very standard way. How would I know if the same request processing is used or if a new context instance is used per request? I don't do anything to deal with contexts at all. There's no reason for me to use contexts when I just want to insert and delete items from a database. I didn't attach somewhere before, so situation here is impossible

Comment: I've seen all the related questions about this topic, and even your own responses before. The answer is simply not clear. There should be a very SIMPLE answer to this, like if(!Object.AlreadyAttached()){AttachObject }else { ClearAttachments(); }

Comment: *How do I know if it will be loaded in the same context or not.* You know it because you write the code = you know how do you instantiate the context and how do you use it. *How would I know if the same request processing is used or if a new context instance is used per request?* Again you know it because you write the code. If you don't know if the code is executed in the same request processing as data loading then you have much bigger problem and you should start learning ASP.NET from the beginning.

Comment: The answer to your simple question is not simple at all because to know if entity is attached you must ask context, not the entity and each context instance can tell you only if it has entity attached but it will not tell you if entity is attached to other instance (the exception you got). So the solution is not to use that *simple solution* but to understand your code and use EF context correctly.

Comment: This wouldn't be a problem if everything about the design of ASP.NET wasn't so overly complicated. What code are you talking about? It simply isn't clear from what you said. There is no context code anywhere here. All the object context code is auto-generated in Visual Studio, no one is suppose to need to deal with that. I've shown you all the relevant code that I have used, and you are talking about things that do not exist in my own code. I didn't "write the code" because Entity framework autogenerates it. I'm asking what do I do, in the relevant code I wrote.

Comment: I cannot find a single example on the internet where you "ask the context" properly and in an easy manner. Some create repositories and such, but this is a very minor issue that does not require something so complicated. I understand my code, what I don't understand is the entity framework's code.

Comment: The context is `this.entities` - that is the code you must somewhere instantiate.

Comment: Yes that context is created in auto-generated code in the constructor. New is used to initiate it. 
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();  -----then object sets and entity sets are established in the autogenerated designer code. But you never have to deal with them, because everything works as is.

Comment: Would something like this truly be necessary? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Comment: No it is not needed. What technology are you using in your code exactly? The instance context is not usually created by autogenerated code. Is it some scaffolding, dynamic data, data sources or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure. My autogenerated code is using using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.ComponentModel;-----  And inherits ObjectContext class. And it calls:    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;  
            OnContextCreated();       ------     I simply call that autogenerated class with "new". And all the queries work after that, no further code is needed. I'm simply using an MSSQL server database and basic data tables. I don't know of any technology names other than simply I'm using Entity Framework. Sorry if this is not helpful.

Comment: Yes that is correct. This autogenerated class is context I'm referring and the call of `new` creates the instance of that context. Are you sure that `list_to_del` is retrieved by the same instance used to delete modules?

Comment: *gasp* No it's not! The query is called in a separate "new Entities()" type thing. Let me replace that query with a function brb.

Comment: Wow that worked. No more errors. So usually instead of calling queries, I call functions from each table's class (which has its own instance of context), but this time, I wrote out a query list_to_del, of another table, inside another table's class. So it used a separate context for that. So when I remove that query, and instead replace it with a function like ModuleClass.GetModulesByID(userid), then the correct entity set or context is used. And that seems to work.

Comment: Updated the main thread. Finally I wanted to ask, I know that queries should be called via using () so that it is disposed, but I also know that they are automatically disposed too. So it is not absolutely necessary, but why is it recommended so strongly? If so, where should I call Dispose() in my class, if I don't know when I won't need it anymore?

Comment: It is not query - query is the linq command you execute. `this.entities` is a context and context must be disposed to release its resources. You must build your own infrastructure and dispose the context for example at the end of request processing when you are sure that you will not need it.

Comment: Ok yes, I meant the context must be disposed of. But doesn't garbage collection already dispose of the object once the instance of that class is gone anyway?

Comment: Garbage collection is undeterministic so you don't know when it happens and because of that IDisposable interface exists to tell developer to release instance redources as soon as possible by calling Dispose manually.

Comment: Guys, take it to chat, we are looking at pruning this comment stream.  There's not much useful stuff in here.